# When to use Iterable, when to use Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I have to implement class `Incrementer` and it suppose to implement `Iterable` I do not really get why it should implement `Iterable<Integer>` instead of `Iterator<Integer>`? I do not ask for solution just the usage of Interfaces.

Why the method `in(int,int)` is static?

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int k : in(1, 10)) System.out.print(k + " ");
    System.out.println();

    for(int k : in(1, 10).by(2)) System.out.print(k + " ");
    System.out.println();

    for(int k : in(10, 1)) System.out.print(k + " ");
    System.out.println();


    for(int k : in(1, 10).by(-1)) System.out.print(k + " ");
    System.out.println();

    Incrementer inc;
    for (int i : inc = in(1,10) ) {
      if (i == 4) inc.by(2);
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i : inc = in(1,10) ) {
      if (i == 8) inc.by(-2);
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int k : inc = in(10, 1)) {
      if (k == 5) inc.by(1);
      System.out.print(k + " ");
    }

  }  
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 3 5 7 9 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 6 8 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 6 4 2 
10 9 8 7 6 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: If you don't implement `Iterable`, you cannot use your class in a foreach loop as you currently do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Iterable` class has a method `iterator()` which returns an instance of `Iterator` class which can be used to iterate objects.Once you have `Iterator` class instance,you can use `hasNext()` and `next()` methods to iterate the elements in your class

Comment: Thank you but where should I keep field `val` representing Integer in class which implements `Iterator` or `Iterable`?

Comment: The most visible change of this interface however is that it allows usage in foreach loops

Comment: Why the method `in(int,int)` is static?

Comment: @fge,yes you are 100% right.Forgot to mention that in my answer.We can just as well have a method which gives an instance of Iterator but would not be able to use in a for each loop.

Comment: +1 to your comment,post this as a answer

Comment: Why? Just edit your answer and add it ;)

Comment: @fge  Its a strong point ,the only reason why we should implement an Iterable instead of working on an Iterator instance directly.therefore you should post this point as a separate answer,including the concept of for each loop

Comment: Thank you really much!!!!!!!!!!! Please could take a look at solution please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577870/iterator-returns-wrong-integer-values

Answer (score 1):

While designing a class if we want to provide iterator functionality , we implement Iterable interface. Now Iterable interface has method `Iterator<T> iterator()` so u need to write implementation of iterator inside your class.

You should look at source code of collection classes ( which implements Collection Interface ) they have same kind of implementation.

So basically you need to use both interfaces to provide iterator functionality in your class.