# Iterator returns wrong integer values

Tags: java, iterator, integer, iterable

I have to implement class `Incrementer` and it suppose to implement `Iterable`.

**The output should be:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 3 5 7 9 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 6 8 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 6 4 2 
10 9 8 7 6 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

**I do get:**

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
3 5 7 9 11 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 

2 3 4 6 8 10 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 8 7 6 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

My `Incrementer` class looks like that:

```
    package in;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Incrementer implements Iterable<Integer> {
    int val, step, a, b;

    private Incrementer(int a, int b, int step) {
        this.step = step;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        if (step > 0)
            val = a;
        else
            val = b;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (step < 0 && val > a)
                    return true;
                else if (step > 0 && val < b)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                return val += step;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
            }
        };
    }

    public static Incrementer in(int a, int b) {
        ///tu zmieniamy tresc dla ostatniego przypadku

        if (a < b)
            return new Incrementer(a, b, 1);
        else
            return new Incrementer(b, a, -1);
    }

    public Incrementer by(int step) {
        this.step = step;
        if (this.step < 0 && this.a < this.b || this.step > 0 && this.a > this.b) {
            int tmp = this.a;
            this.a = this.b;
            this.b = tmp;
        }
        return this;
    }

}
```

and the Testcode:

```
package in;
import static in.Incrementer.*;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int k : in(1, 10)) System.out.print(k + " ");
    System.out.println();


    for(int k : in(1, 10).by(2)) System.out.print(k + " ");
    System.out.println();

    for(int k : in(10, 1)) System.out.print(k + " ");
    System.out.println();

    for(int k : in(1, 10).by(-1)) System.out.print(k + " ");
    System.out.println();

    Incrementer inc;
    for (int i : inc = in(1,10) ) {
      if (i == 4) inc.by(2);
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i : inc = in(1,10) ) {
      if (i == 8) inc.by(-2);
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int k : inc = in(10, 1)) {
      if (k == 5) inc.by(1);
      System.out.print(k + " ");
    }

  }


}
```

I do not know where I did mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is that you doesn't initialize `val`, so it will start at `0` (the default value).

In your second example, you will `return val += step;`, with `val = 0` and `step = 2`, so it will start at `2` and continue from there.

In your third example, `a = 10`, `b = 1`, `step = -1` and `val = 0`, so you will not enter in

```
if (step < 0 && val > a)
```

because `val < a`, and you will not enter in

```
else if (step > 0 && val < b)
```

because `step < 0`.

**EDIT:**

In the edited post, you should modify the `next()` method to return `val`, and only increase it after :

```
@Override
public Integer next() {
    int ret = val;
    val += step;
    return val;
}
```

You should also modify the conditions in the `hasNext()`:

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if (step < 0 && val >= a)
        return true;
    else if (step > 0 && val <= b)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

To make you fourth test work, you will have to change the `by()` method to invert `a` and `b` if needed:

```
public Incrementer by(int step) {
    if ((this.step<0)!=(step<0) && this.val==this.a)
        this.val = this.b;
    else if ((this.step<0)!=(step<0) && this.val==this.b) 
        this.val = this.a;
    else if (this.val!=this.a && this.val!=this.b) {
        this.val -= this.step;
        this.val += step;
    }
    this.step = step;

    return this;
}
```

You can also test the inverse case:

```
for(int k : in(10, 1).by(1)) System.out.print(k + " ");
```

---

Here is the complete code:

```
public class Incrementer implements Iterable<Integer> {
    int val, step, a, b;

    private Incrementer(int a, int b, int step) {
        this.step = step;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        if (step > 0)
            val = a;
        else
            val = b;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (step < 0 && val >= a)
                    return true;
                else if (step > 0 && val <= b)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Integer next() {
                int ret = val;
                val += step;
                return ret;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
            }
        };
    }

    public static Incrementer in(int a, int b) {
        ///tu zmieniamy tresc dla ostatniego przypadku

        if (a < b)
            return new Incrementer(a, b, 1);
        else
            return new Incrementer(b, a, -1);
    }

    public Incrementer by(int step) {
        if ((this.step<0)!=(step<0) && this.val==this.a)
            this.val = this.b;
        else if ((this.step<0)!=(step<0) && this.val==this.b)
            this.val = this.a;
        else if (this.val!=this.a && this.val!=this.b) {
            this.val -= this.step;
            this.val += step;
        }
        this.step = step;

        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you I have edited OP. Please take a look. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you I edited code again, like you said. But unfortunatelly the output is the same as posted in the original post. Please take a look.

Oh the op is edited

Answer (score 2):

You make one fundamental mistake to begin with: an `Iterable` is supposed to be able to issue infinitely many `Iterator`s, but you can only issue one.

Each `Iterator` should have sufficient internal state so that it can be able to iterate over your set of values.

To fix this and your other problem at the same time, change your code to this in `iterator()`:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Integer>() {
        int val = a; // <-- HERE
```

and change your `.next()` to:

```
public Integer next()
{
    int ret = val;
    val += step;
    return ret;
}
```

and remove your other `val`.

(also, I'd suggest you rename `a` to `start` and `b` to `end`)

---

Final remark: in order to fully obey the contract of `Iterator`, your `.remove()` should do that:

```
public void remove()
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

And no, you don't need to declare that the method throws this exception since it is an *unchecked* exception. See javadoc for `RuntimeException`.

Comment: How should I set `start` `end` and `step` to the iterator. I do not know how to access it by method `by()`. Example `in(1, 10).by(-1)` `start` should be set to 1, `end` to 10 and `step` tp -1.

Comment: Hmmm... Is that a requirement of your exercise? You are not supposed to be able to modify the behaviour of an iterator while it is running...

Comment: Yes it is unfortunatelly. In the exercise teacher wrote:   // W trakcie iteracji można zmieniac krok which means While iterating you can change the step. But this is very bad teacher(not mine teacher).

Comment: Oh dear... A teacher asking to break a contract on purpose :/